# Android: Is there a way to use autoSize in a textView without breaking individual words?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I'm trying to make an app (well, part of an app) which takes an input string from the user and displays it fullscreen, in a different fragment. Which I've got working, but using autoSize on it makes the text so big it gets wrapped, like this:
[image: Android screenshot showing the text "Moo!!!!!!!" split over multiple lines]

Not all words get broken if they're small enough:
[image: Android screenshot showing the text "moooooooooo and again", with the extended "moo" being split over multiple lines]

Looking through the docs (and some web searching), these were the only XML attributes that seemed relevant:

```
android:breakStrategy="simple"
android:ellipsize="none"
android:hyphenationFrequency="none"
```

None of them seemed to change the behaviour. About the only thing I could find that makes a difference is `android:singleLine="true"` but that makes things worse:
[image: Android screenshot showing the text "Moo" with only the first two letters visible]
and I'm not sure I want to know how much worse that makes it when there's multiple words.

I've pared the fragment layout down to basically the minimum possible that I can think of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frag_big_text_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/big_text_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textColor="@color/big_text_foreground"
    
        android:breakStrategy="simple"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:hyphenationFrequency="none"
        
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="240sp"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="14sp"
        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1px"
        
        tools:gravity="center"
        tools:targetApi="m"
        tools:text="BIG TEXT HERE"/>
    
</FrameLayout>
```

I know I could set the `autoSizeMaxTestSize` to something lower that should fit most phone screens, but then it won't fill the screen on a tablet (and don't worry about targeting `m`, my AVD is set to match the specs of my phone, which is on API 29). The code that sets the current text is also pretty simple:`bigTextView.text = messageList[index]` (and it's definitely not a problem with the list it's pulling from, since I tried hard coding it with `bigTextView.text = "thisisareallylongword"`, same result).

I'm hoping this is one case where I'm missing something obvious and don't have to reinvent the wheel. Wheels aren't my area of expertise, I figured that out when I had to fix a broken `pip` install.

But whatever reinvention or stupid intervention is required, can anyone help me out?